# UI defect in job recommendation section on profile page

Tags: bug, design

[image]

The UI defect is found in job recommendation section on my profile page.

The tag goes out of the bound.

The browser I am using is Chrome with Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).